# Aligning desktop icons in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-icons

I am using Kubuntu. Currently my desktop is in **Folder Layout** mode. I have tried to align the icons on my desktop by selecting **Align to grid** in icons option in desktop. Still my icons are not properly aligned.

[image: Screenshot of desktop showing icons not aligned nicely]

This is so easy in Ubuntu by right clicking and selecting **align**. Can anyone please tell me how can I align my desktop icons in Kubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I came here by searching for "kubuntu grid desktop". I want the normal desktop, but with a 
grid, so icons get arranged nicely.

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-containments-addons
```

Then right-click desktop > "Desktop Settings" and select "Grid Desktop" as layout.

Note that the widgets must be unlocked for the "Layout" option to be enabled.

Tested on Kubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

The "Folder Layout" has same options as the "Folder Views" plasma videget.

Right click the desktop. There should be option: Folder View Settings.

[image]

1) Pick the Display option.

2) Align to grid.

3) Apply.

[image]

Comment: I have already selected that, still the icons are not properly aligned. Check the screen shot: http://picpaste.com/tool-lsNn9Y8A.png